# Windows Server 2008 (x64) won't boot past BIOS screen

Tags: windows-server-2008, boot, domain-controller

Since a month or so ago I inherited responsibility for small network administration for my sins.  The domain controller (yes there is only one, and yes I know it is best practice to have two even in a small domain setup) went down overnight and I have been trying all day to get it back up and running.  Unfortunately this machine also administers our entire Active Directory setup:

1. It goes through the BIOS without any errors, nothing whatsoever
2. It gets into the “select safe mode, safe mode with networking, normal” etc and if you select either of the safe mode options it loads a few files then reboots.  If you select normal it just runs for a bit (doesn’t get to the windows splash screen) and then reboots again.
3. If you select windows repair, it asks for an image to repair too: however it would appear that none was taken that can be used (!!) or one is not being shown.
4. I have tried repairing the boot sector and the boot configuration using `bootrec.exe`, both which it says were completed successfully but still it doesn’t work.
5. I have tried swapping the drives into another server to rule out hardware and that didn’t work either so clearly it’s the OS.
6. I have tried running `chkdsk` which ran fine, and also memory check which was also fine.

We do have another machine on the network that was installed as a DC so when we decommission the current infrastructure but when I try and "promote" this to the lead DC then I get “you cannot modify domain or trust information because a PDC emulator cannot be contacted" so I am unable to replicate the Active Directory details.

Comment: Try booting the Windows CD and selecting the repair options. Cross your fingers that it works, you're pretty close to SOL.

Comment: What is the status of your backups?

Comment: Chris: thanks for the quick response, sorry I should have added that I already tried the windows repair options, there is no image stored to repair from image (remember this is 2008 server so file/file copy doesnt work as its image based install) so that leaves me command prompt, and memory check as the only other options.

Comment: I also tried StartRep, and all of the Boot repair options as mentioned above in the thinking it was a boot sector corruption: but to no avail.  The only mild progression being the startrep but it just says it cant be recovered automatically and it gives me no pointers what is wrong.

Comment: Bart: again thanks to you also.  There are backups of the data / file shares etc but it would appear the previous sysadmins have not taken any system images or restore points to work from or restore back to.

Comment: The data may be intact (which is good) but if there's no system-level backups your AD information may be hosed. You might have to restore to a new server and begin rebuilding from scratch, then restore the data and alter the permissions on the restored data to your users. How many users are you talking about here?

Comment: When you boot it into safe mode how far does it get, and what driver is the last one it reports as loading before rebooting?

Comment: Thats what I was dreading anyone saying, we arent talking about too many users as the company is in a transition state at the moment, but I wanted to try and maintain something at least.  The problem will be trying to reattach the MSA after with all the data on (so then I can force ownership of everything as needed to then "give out" permissions to those that need it.

Comment: Helvik: it goes through about 10-15 files, and I seem to remember the last one being CI.dll or something.

Comment: If you can establish exactly which driver is the last one loaded that can help zero in on similar issues, it might just be possible to boot into the recovery console and carry out repairs (such as uninstalling a patch if that is the issue) from the command line provided you can get an issue to match your symptoms.

Comment: OKay thanks Helvick, I will look tomorrow when I am back in the office but I think that it is CI.dll but still you would think that an error would be displayed ... all it does is get that far into starting safe mode and then reboots.

Comment: This is a pattern with severe driver issues, I've never seen it happen on 2008 R2 but I have seen it (often) on XP\2003, and occasionally on Vista\Windows 7. In all cases where it's been recoverable I've been able to tie the last driver loaded message to an issue with a patch or a driver that can be removed from the command line. Not all such issues are recoverable but its worth a shot.

Comment: Well I see what you mean, clearly something happened last night as everything went down at the same time (but I guess with the DC running the DNS then nothing would resolve ....) I am wondering if its worth just removing any patch applied yesterday by Windows Update, if that is possible??

Comment: Helvick: thanks for your support last night, I have tried a few things this morning but to no avail.  Booting into safemode still restarts when it gets to CI.DLL so I am searching for possible solutions based on this.  If you have any thoughts they would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Okay I spoke to HP just now and they suggested copying over a new CI.dll and working from that way, I tried doing this: and while it still wont boot it IS giving me something different that being that the CI.dll is corrupt.  So at least I have something to work with now.

Comment: Annoying ... am now getting problems with it verifying the digital signature.  Going to try the f8 override option to see if that works ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Enterprise Agreement with Software Assurance, you could take advantage of [Microsoft DaRT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/dart-v10/) (Diagnostics and Recovery Toolset).

DaRT is based on Windows PE, and includes a strong set of tools for troubleshooting and recovering unusable systems. It includes a registry editor, file explorer, and crash analyzer; as well as tools to restore files, repair disks, scan for viruses and more.

Answer (score 0):

You could try booting from a linux live CD and mounting the drive so you can scan it for more errors. If you're able to mount the drive successfully and the scan comes back clean, you should be able to at least access/transfer the files that are on that hard drive.

Comment: That won't help if the corruption is at a different level and his registry files are hosed, though. Can't easily copy files from A to B to restore it like that, to my knowledge. And even if he brought another AD server up, it would be so out of sync he could have serious problems with getting it running properly. If he doesn't have many users he may have to actually rebuild the whole thing from scratch, if there are no backups.

Comment: Thanks byachna, there are no files on there that I need to keep.  All of the shared directories are located on a storageworks servere attached through MSA: they are all fine asides from being locked from users as a result of lack of DC which controls the permissions.  Its more the activedirectory that I am worried about, and the DC itself obviously, the CHKDSK didnt find any drive errors so you think the linux live cd would perhaps deduce more logical errors that could be causing the problem? the thing that makes me worry is that I cant see ANY errors giving me a hint as to where I can look :(

Comment: Bart: I have tried bringing up another machine on the network as the DC but it needs to sync with the PDC / Primary Domain Controller to get the AD data which of course is down.

Comment: Incidentally I have also tried the sfc.exe /scannow utility as well but that just refuses to do anything.  The drives themselves dont appear to be producing any errors, and all status lights arent indicating everything.

Comment: Does anyone have any further comments? I am trying to upgrade Server 2008 x64 to Server 2008 R2 in the hope that it will jog the problem away, but Windows is refusing to continue the upgrade from disk as I booted from disk.  Catch 22: I cant boot into windows normally as it is asking, so what now?

Comment: It wouldnt be so bad, but apparently the backup domain controller needs to have the one discussed here up and running to sync itself.  I cant just reinstall as otherwise will lose the active directory stuff.